# VS Code: How do I stop Prettier from adding a new line at the end of my JS file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, visual-studio-code, prettier

I installed Prettier and changed the settings to format on save. I ran Firebase deploy and now I'm getting an error:

`172:6   error    Newline not allowed at end of file    eol-last`

I see that when I format on save, it's adding a new line at the end. How do I force Prettier to not do this?

Comment: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/6360 This discussion indicates to me that prettier doesn't allow this.

Comment: Learn to live with it. A long time ago this bothered me. Not with prettier, but more bothersome was that some applications would not read the last line of text files that didnt end with a newline. Its actually a POSIX standard for text files to end with a new line. Now it bothers me when there is no empty line at the end of a file

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the Prettier extension to not add a new line at the end of file by setting the "insertFinalNewLine" option to "false" in your prettier configuration file. Like this:

```
  {
    "insertFinalNewLine": "false"
  }
```

Or you can set "proseWrap" to "never" to disable automatic line-wrapping and to not add newline at the end of file. Like this:

```
{
 "proseWrap": "never"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This gives an error: `Invalid endOfLine value. Expected "auto", "cr", "crlf" or "lf", but received "none".`